# Showing that a linear transformation is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the linear transformation $L_1: V \rightarrow V$ (where $V = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$  is the vector space of polynomials with complex coefficients) defined as:

$L_1(f(x,y)) =  \frac{f(x,y)+f(y,x)}{2}$

I want to find out if $L_1$ is diagonalizable. To do this I first tried to find the matrix representation of $L_1$ by constructing a standard basis $\{1,x,y,x^2,xy,y^2,...\}$ for $V$ and then applying the transformation on this basis. However, this approach feels very clumsy. Is there any other way I could approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: As you stated the question, $V$ is the vector space of all complex polynomials, so is an infinite dimensional vector space. It is possible that you indeed wanted to say that $V$ is the vector space of all complex polynomials whose degree doesn't exceed a certain value $n$?

Comment: You should have that $L_1^2 = L_1$, so it is a projection operator onto its image. The operator $L_2 = 1-L_1$ is the complementary projection. Can you show that $V = \ker L_1 \oplus \mathrm{im} L_1$? (By the way, I assume “diagonalisable” for an operator on an infinite dimensional space means that the space is the direct sum of eigenspaces.)

Comment: Álvaro, no I mean the infinite vector space.

Comment: Joppy, I have been able to show that $V$ is the direct sum of the kernel and image. And you’re right, I need to show that the direct sum of all eigenspaces is equal to V. Maybe I should just try to find the eigenvalues then.